# что ещё помимо "404.html" необходимо __статическому__ веб серверу?

Tags: nginx, http

Есть абстрактный (*например гитхаб*) сервер `http`/`https`, раздающий **исключительно статику**

вопрос:

Для каких кодов состояния помимо 404 необходимо создать "404.html"?

---

- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_кодов_состояния_HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

Comment: Даже для 404 создавать ничего не обязательно, так что вопрос непонятен

Comment: Ну и что такое гитхаб-сервер тоже непонятно

Comment: @andreymal, следуя вашей логике: сайт создавать - тоже не обязательно. Вы действительно не знаете что такое github pages или просто зануда?

Comment: Во-первых, да, сайт создавать тоже никто не заставляет :) Во-вторых, github pages не абстрактный, а вполне конкретный, и он [позволяет кастомизировать только страницу 404](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site) и больше ничего, другие коды ошибок вы всё равно не сможете кастомизировать при всём желании

Comment: @andreymal, yууу, а например какие-нибудь __"технические работы"__ из какой-нибудь `cpanel`. Предположу что в таком случае http `503`?

Comment: Это как в статике получится `503`? Все ошибки на `40x` - можно завернуть на один файл и не париться.